# C/C++ divisions with double and following shift operation

Tags: c++, c, linux, casting, double

can anybody explain why following code generates different results?

```
double zaehler = -20;
double teiler = 0.08;
printf("ergebnis = %d \n", ((int) (zaehler/teiler)) << 7 );
printf("ergebnis = %d \n", (int) (-20/0.08) << 7 );
```

Results:

```
ergebnis = -31872 
ergebnis = -32000
```

Many thanks ahead

Comment: They both print -32000 for me (the result I expected). Are you sure you pasted the code right? What compiler are you using?

Comment: [Cannot repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc428c5f024dd909)

Comment: Perhaps - In one you have two memory locations with double "precision", with floating point error.  in the other, you have two literals, with precise values, i.e. no errors down in the lower bits.  i.e. the variable _teiler_ may look like 0.080000000234526 in memory

Comment: I second @dvnrrs's observation

Comment: **Comments about rounding errors / loss of precision are incorrect**; there's something else going on. I suspect the OP removed some important details in the process of trying to whittle his code down to a minimal example, or something along those lines.

Comment: Values are same: http://ideone.com/4uu67A http://ideone.com/Gl11Km

Comment: See http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/ and the part about "Composing larger expressions" (The first line got fewer chances to be inlined by the compiler so one line can be computed at runtime while the other is computed during computation... with potentially different precisions like 80 vs 64 bits 'doubles'... depends on the compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very small rounding difference, within the range possible for the difference between 64 and 80 bits, could account for the different output. The combination of the truncate to int and shift can magnify a tiny difference. This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    double zaehler = -20;
    double teiler = 0.08;
    printf("ergebnis = %d \n", (int) (zaehler/teiler) );
    printf("ergebnis = %d \n", (int) (-20/0.08));
}
```

prints:

```
ergebnis = -249 
ergebnis = -250
```

If the division gives an answer even a tiny bit less than 250 the truncation to int will get 249. I suggest rounding instead of truncating.

Eclipse, MinGW:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
g++ -o TestCPP.exe main.o
```